# Why was my recent question about Jewish CEO's deleted?

Tags: discussion, offensive-claims

Recently I asked a question and then forgot about it. But I found that it was deleted by mods. Why was it deleted? The mods didn't give any reason.

Comment: Just to note it, I feel like a lot of the stuff that I've seen from you has been about who's a Jew, e.g. the newest question, ["Was Red Orchestra led by Jews?"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39247/was-red-orchestra-led-by-jews), which asks if a group of people were Jews, much like this deleted question about Jewish CEO's which boiled down to you not liking that the US classifies Jewish people as "white".  You might get better responses on topics with more common interest/relevance.

Comment: I'm surprised you're banned from asking questions about claims made on the Daily Stormer, considering that two questions about claims posted on Stormfront (a different website, but both similar in ideology) are well received: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18916/do-the-jewish-control-a-larger-proportion-of-u-s-wealth-than-their-proportion-i (15 upvotes, 0 downvotes) and https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19974/are-american-media-controlled-mostly-by-jews (52 upvotes, 0 downvotes)

Comment: Two questions *from over three years ago.* They're not a valid comparison (and if they were,  it would suggest the old questions are now off-topic, not that the new one should be allowed).

Answer (score 2):

My apologies over the lack of a comment. I held back while the moderators discussed what an appropriate level of response should be.

For more information about how this question was inappropriate, please see your history of "mod messages".